# How to get application for application event log

Tags: powershell, windows-event-log

I have some servers that are commonly having error 1000s. I want to find if it's the same application all the time, or if it's different applications. I am using this:

```
Get-EventLog application 1000 -entrytype error -newest 10 | select timegenerated,message | Export-Csv errors.csv
```

and the output shows the application name (specifically the exe file) as part of the multi-line message field.

I have not been able to figure out how to extract just the application name from the output.

Piping the output to Get-Member makes it look like the message field is an array, but I cannot figure out how to extract that part of the array at this point.

---

```
Get-EventLog application 1000 -entrytype error -newest 10 | %{$_.machinename,$_.timegenerated,$_.ReplacementStrings[0]}
```

This gives me the output I want, except it's generated over three lines, and Export-CSV doesn't want to parse it properly. How can I get them all on one line?

Comment: Check my latest update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not going to be accurate for all event types, but the property `ReplacementStrings` is an array where the first element is the name of the executable when looking at InstanceID 1000:

```
> Get-EventLog application 1000 -entrytype error -newest 10 | %{$_.ReplacementStrings[0]}
Ssms.exe
Ssms.exe
Ssms.exe
uniStudio.exe
SwyxIt!.exe
Ssms.exe
uniRTE.exe
uniStudio.exe
Ssms.exe
Ssms.exe
```

My PS-foo is weak at this time of the morning, but I'm sure there's a way to combine that with your `select` command and thus export them into your CSV.

---

As per your update; this will get you the output you need in a table format. I don't know how well it will play with `export-csv` though:

```
Get-EventLog application 1000 -entrytype error -newest 10|Format-Table @{Expression={$_.machinename};Label="Machine Name";width=25},@{Expression={$_.timegenerated.DateTime};Label="DateTime";width=25},@{Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[0]};Label="EXEName";width=25}
```

---

Never mind; I went way too complicated in my last update. This should work just fine (I knew I'd be better later in the day):

```
> Get-EventLog application 1000 -entrytype error -newest 10|Select-Object  timegenerated,message,@{name='Executable';expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[0]}}|Export-CSV errors.csv


TimeGenerated                           Message                                 Executable
-------------                           -------                                 ----------
14/01/2014 7:23:13 AM                   Faulting application name: Ssms.exe,... Ssms.exe
13/01/2014 7:26:44 AM                   Faulting application name: Ssms.exe,... Ssms.exe
10/01/2014 7:30:24 AM                   Faulting application name: Ssms.exe,... Ssms.exe
8/01/2014 5:25:13 PM                    The description for Event ID '1000' ... uniStudio.exe
31/12/2013 3:09:58 PM                   The description for Event ID '1000' ... SwyxIt!.exe
19/12/2013 7:35:21 AM                   Faulting application name: Ssms.exe,... Ssms.exe
18/12/2013 2:55:45 PM                   Faulting application name: uniRTE.ex... uniRTE.exe
18/12/2013 9:25:49 AM                   The description for Event ID '1000' ... uniStudio.exe
18/12/2013 7:32:29 AM                   Faulting application name: Ssms.exe,... Ssms.exe
16/12/2013 1:22:38 PM                   Faulting application name: Ssms.exe,... Ssms.exe
```

Comment: if you replace `{...}` with `@{name='Executable';expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[0]}}`, you get a friendlier property name.

Comment: @charleswj81 - you certainly do; I have updated my code snippet